# Уместно ли употребление пословицы в данном контексте

Tags: пословицы

История про персики.
Было у меня 6 персиков. Один из них был самый кривой, некрасивый и вроде бы уже портился.
Я разрезала его, почистила от косточки, отрезала страшную шкурку.
И....
Он оказался самым вкусным из всех.
Вывод:
**Не все золото, что блестит.**

Вопрос - уместно ли употребление пословицы "Не все золото, что блестит" применительно к данной истории?

Answer (score 2):

**Не всё (то) золото, что блестит.**
Значение пословицы таково: оценивать кого-то или что-то нужно по внутреннему содержанию, а не по внешним признакам. Например:
речь может быть правильно составлена и грамотна, но глупа и бессодержательна;
книга может быть ярко издана, но пуста и неинтересна;
идея может быть прекрасно подана и растиражирована, но неисполнима;
товар может иметь «товарный вид» и громкую рекламу, но быть некачественным;
человек может быть красавцем, но злодеем.

Для Вашей ситуации, думаю, больше подойдут такие пословицы:
Не красиво, да скажешь после спасибо.
Криво дерево, да яблоки сладки.
Неказисто дерево, да вкусен плод.
Красотой сыт не будешь.
Не будь пригож, а будь пригоден.
Вид хорош, да по виду не судят.
**Не суди об арбузе по корке...**

Дополнение

1. **И....** Такого знака нет. Многоточие — это три точки подряд (**И...**).
2. Вывод: **н**е все золото, что блестит (со строчной буквы).
3. В толковом словаре Кузнецова:
   **очистить**
   3) освободить от чего-либо засоряющего, убрать лишнее, ненужное.
   *Очистить комнату от разного хлама. Очистить поле от сорняков.*

Вместо "почистить от косточки" лучше написать "**о**чистить от косточки".

Comment: Шикарно. Спасибо.
Но "Красотой сыт не будешь" мне кажется не подходит к данному тексту.

Comment: Вот ещё одна: **_Не суди об арбузе по корке**, а о человеке — по платью._ Можно, как мне кажется, спокойно использовать только первую часть.

Comment: Шикарно? Я тоже так думаю. Пословицы одна лучше другой. Но тогда вопрос нужно принять или хотя бы плюсик поставить.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon, за добрые слова — Вы их нечасто раздаете.

Answer (score 0):

Пословица о другом: "не всё, что выглядит хорошим, является таковым в действительности".
А ваш случай: "не всё, что выглядит плохим, является таковым в действительности".
Второе утверждение никак не связано с первым. Если внешне плохая вещь по свойствам хороша, это ещё не предполагает того, что внешне хорошая вещь может оказаться плохой по свойствам.
На вскидку не припомню пословицы для Вашего случая, но можно было бы употребить нечто вроде: "Не всё то гадость, что плохо выглядит", если бы таковое выражение существовало. Самое близкое по смыслу из того, что помню: "Встречают по одёжке, провожают по уму", это своего рода антоним фразы "Не всё то золото, что блестит", хотя его обычно не к продуктам, а к людям применяют.

Comment: Это прекрасно. Спасибо за развернутый ответ

Answer (score 0):

Вряд ли стоит упоминать именно эту пословицу: из неё не следует обратное (если что-то не блестит, оно всё равно может оказаться золотым - как в вашем случае). Уж лучше припомнить что-нибудь вроде Гадкого утёнка ("**некрасива** [ягодка], **да счастлива**" и т. п.).

Comment: Спасибо. Хороши бы подобрать пословицу соответствующую контексту данной истории

Comment: Пословица, которую я привёл в изменённом виде, есть у Даля (сборник "Пословицы русского народа"): _И не красива, да счастлива. Хоть костлива, да счастлива_

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что формально можно. 
Да, очень возможно, что это не лучший с литературной точки зрения вариант, есть, как вам уже сказали, куда более подходящие. Да, не все эту параллель поймут без пояснений. Но если ставить вопрос ребром, можно или нет, то можно. 
"Золотым" оказался не самый "блестящий" фрукт. Значит, все остальные, которые "блестящие", - не "золото". Где нарушение логики-то, я не пойму?!

Ну а если автор претендует не на глубину анализа, а на быстрое и лёгкое понимание, то смотрите у Даля. Вот первые попавшиеся.

*Черная корова, да белое молочко.

Черен мак, да бояре едят.

Нужды нет, что плохо имя: была бы хорошо вымя.

Мыло серо, да моет бело.*

Comment: Если один не блестящий предмет оказался золотым, то это не значит, что: а) все блестящие предметы не могут быть золотом б) все не блестящие предметы являются золотом. Поговорка "Не всё то золото, что блестит" не означает, что "блестящие" предметы не золото, если золотым оказался не блестящий. Она значит лишь, что вовсе не каждый из блестящих предметов является золотом.Так что нарушение логики в версии автора есть. Мы можем только догадаться, что он имеет в виду, но поговорка применена неверно.

Comment: @Третийглаз а)-б) Да. И что? Эти утверждения никак не опровергают того, что хотя бы один блестящий предмет оказался не золотым. Вешайте правильно кванторы, если вы начали формальной логикой оперировать. *Так что нарушение логики в версии автора есть* - у автора вообще нет отсылки к формальной логике, это ему уже комментаторы вменили. Но у него нет даже нарушения **аналогии**. Ибо он пишет, что **все** "блестящие" предметы оказались "не золотыми". Вы или невнимательно прочитали, или сознательно проигнорировали смысл.

Comment: Где он написал, что все блестящие не золотые? Он сказал, что самый некрасивый персик, был самым вкусным, но не писал, что остальные невкусные или какие-то порченные. Где он, по-Вашему, перешёл ту грань, которая бы отрицала "золотистость" всех красивых плодов? "Самый вкусный" не равно "единственный". Да, фраза не опровергает того, что "хотя бы один блестящий предмет оказался не золотым", но и никак не указывает на это. Приписывать такое значение фразе это уже произвольная интерпретация..В ней этого не сказано.

Comment: *Где он написал, что все блестящие не золотые?* "Он оказался самым вкусным из всех".

Comment: *"Самый вкусный" не равно "единственный".* - эк вас штормит. Если "самый" - то именно **единственный**. Из всех. У вас есть другое понимание? Даже если применять нестрогий критерий (самый = лучший или равен), то все равно нашлись те, которые хуже. Вариант "все одинаково вкусные" я отметаю, ибо на человеческом языке "самый" все-таки не предполагает равного качества у всех.

Comment: Самый вкусный, но ведь тоже вкусный, а не невкусный, так ведь? Проблема в том, что мы по-разному понимаем "золото". Оно бывает разной пробы, но всё равно остаётся золотом. А Вы же решили назвать золотом только "самое". Только завтра он купит персик "ещё вкуснее", и что тогда будет с Вашим пониманием "золота"? Разжалуете "самый вкусный" в "серебро"? Должна быть грань "вкусноты", за которой продукты считаются "золотом". Золото — это не Грааль, чтобы быть в единственном экземпляре. Зубная коронка и корона из одного материала, хотя ценность у них разная, всё это золото.

Comment: Мне не очень интересно ваше понимание "золота". Оно здесь вообще без нужды. В пословицах это своего рода *объективизация* (чуть ли не персонификация) некоей идеи. Его и надо понимать как идею. Но я пошел вам навстречу и открыл тему  для ваших объяснений. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453394