# Толкование пословиц

Tags: пословицы

Вопрос [Уместно ли употребление пословицы в данном контексте](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453360) заставил меня в очередной раз задуматься над коллективным пониманием пословиц. 
Я кое-что для себя сформулировал, но все пока очень непричесано, решил для начала спросить, а не в открытую ли я дверь ломлюсь.

Поясняю суть проблемы на примере упомянутого вопроса.
Всякая пословица есть некая обобщенная мудрость, изложенная в виде простого утверждения-примера. Лица или действующие объекты в пословице могут быть разные. Скажем, одна и та же мысль выражается в следующих пословицах (из Даля):

*Черная корова, да белое молочко.

Черен мак, да бояре едят.

Нужды нет, что плохо имя: была бы хорошо вымя.

Мыло серо, да моет бело.*

Если чем и различаются, то акцентами, да и то очень незначительными. Вряд ли кто сможет найти разницу самой идеи, здесь выраженной.

При этом пословица "*Не все золото, что блестит*" - с тем же смыслом - воспринимается (и я в этом неоднократно убеждался на этом и других примерах) совершенно "не в тему" предыдущего. 
***Может ли кто-то объяснить разницу? Между "Черна коровка, да молоко бело" и "Не все золото, что блестит".***

На всякий случай. Тут апеллируют к законам формальной логики. Дескать, формально - не оно. Вот, дескать, если бы было ***"Золото, а не блестит"*** - вот тогда да, оно самое. Но, мне кажется, предки наши прекрасно оперировали этими законами. Ибо тождественного последнему (по форме и содержанию) высказывания даже у Даля не обнаружено (поправьте, если таки есть), а вот само это "Не все золото, что блестит" прекрасно применяется вместо того отсутствующего. То есть как эквивалент из списка "Черна коровка..."  Ну пока кто-то из формалистов не вмешается.

Поэтому вторая часть вопроса.
В чем смысловая разница между ***"Не все золото, что блестит"*** и ***"Золото, а не  блестит"***? А между ***"Золото, а не блестит"*** и ***"Черна коровка - а молоко бело"***?

Повторюсь, я будучи весьма подкованным в этой самой формальной логике, не ощущаю значительной разницы в понимании - во всех трех случаях.

---

Давайте так...
(1.1) Черная корова, да белое молочко.
(1.2) Черен мак, да бояре едят.
(1.3) Нужды нет, что плохо имя: была бы хорошо вымя.
(1.4) Мыло серо, да моет бело.
(2.1) Золото, а не блестит.
(2.2) Не блестит, а золото.
(3) Не все золото, что блестит.

Answer (score 2):

Разница в направленности: про корову поговорка оптимистична (знай: оно лучше, чем кажется), а та, что про золото, - пессимистична (наткнувшись на что-то заманчивое, не спеши радоваться).

Comment: Очень субъективно. По мне так они одинаково реалистичны. Да я и о восприятии спрашиваю, а о смысловом обобщении.

Answer (score 1):

Согласен, смыслы близкие. Не знаю, скажу ли я что-то помимо того, что очевидно для всех, но всё же попытаюсь ответить.

- *Черна коровка, да молоко бело.* Чёрное в таких пословицах несёт смысл чего-то плохого, неказистого. То есть коровка ничего собой не представляет особенного с виду, а молоко даёт вкусное.
- *Не всё то золото, что блестит.* Здесь смысл в том, что что-то может "блестеть", казаться очень привлекательным, а внутри оказаться пустышкой.

***То есть в первом случае что-то плохое с виду оказывается хорошим, а во втором наоборот.***

Есть ещё словосочетание *"гроб повапленный",* отражающее ситуацию из второй пословицы. Это из евангельской фразы: *Горе вам книжницы и фарисее лицемери, яко подобитеся гробом повапленым, иже внеуду (снаружи) убо являются красны, внутрьуду (внутри) же полни суть костей мертвых и всякия нечистоты.* "Повапленный" значит "окрашенный". Цитирую с [Академика](https://phraseology.academic.ru/2839/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9): ***Гроб повапленный.*** Устар. 1. То, что прикрывается наружным блеском, а на самом деле ничтожно, пусто, никуда не годно. 2. Внешне привлекательный, но гнусный, отвратительный человек.

Вторая часть вопроса. На второй вопрос из двух отвечу, что, на мой взгляд, смысл здесь один, разница лишь в порядке: *хорошее, а по виду этого не скажешь* и *неказисто, однако хорошее.* Поэтому на первый вопрос второй части сказал бы примерно то же, что и на первую часть вопроса, приравняв фразы из второго вопроса второй части.

Comment: Я пронумеровал утверждения (см. текст вопроса). Я правильно понимаю, что вы приравниваете (1.1) и  (2.1) и противопоставляете оба (3)?! А между (2.1) и (2.2)  разница есть?!

Comment: Да, приравниваю: порядок утверждений другой, но смысл такой же. (2.1) и (2.2) точно так же: один смысл при разном порядке.